# select by date from appngine

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

First all I sorry on my english.
I development in gwt and I have appengine server.
I have question
1) how I can select row by date.
I write this

```
    String query = "select key from " + MyClass.class.getName();
    Query q = pm.newQuery(query);
    String filter = "date<= 'Tue Mar 04 19:34:12 IST 2014'";
    q.setFilter(filter);
    int totalAgendaToNextWeekCounter += ((List<Integer>) q.execute()).size();
```

but is not work i get always 0.
thank you everybody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will help to convert the date parameter from a string to a java.util.Date, and pass it as a query parameter, in something like:

```
Query q = pm.newQuery(query);
int totalAgendaToNextWeekCounter = 0;
try {
    java.text.DateFormat dateformat = java.text.DateFormat.getDateInstance();
    java.util.Date paramDate = dateformat.parse("2014-03-04T19:34:12");
    String query = "select key from " + MyClass.class.getName();
    q.setFilter( "date <= :paramDate" );
    totalAgendaToNextWeekCounter = ((List<Integer>) q.execute(paramDate)).size();
}
catch (java.text.ParseException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(logName).severe("");
}
finally {
    q.closeAll();
}
```

This may not fit exactly in your program, but the important thing is not to pass the date parameter as a string.